How to Handle Dynamic Parameters in Request Object for WireMock API Testing .Net?
I am trying to create a request object with a dynamic parameter for testing an API endpoint using WireMock. Below is my current implementation:
var response = new Response
{
    CustomerId = CustomerReference,
    CustomerEmail = _customerInfo.EmailAddress,
    CustomerName = _customerInfo.FirstName + " " + _customerInfo.LastName,
    RequestDate = DateTime.UtcNow
};

var request = new Request
{
    CustomerEmail = customerEmail,
    CustomerId = customerId,
    CustomerName = customerName,
    RequestReference = "shouldbedynamic",
};

WireMockApiFake
    .Given(Request.Create()
        .WithPath("/api/customer")
        .UsingPost()
        .WithBodyAsJson(request))
    .RespondWith(Response.Create()
        .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        .WithBodyAsJson(response));

The issue is that the RequestReference field in the Request object is dynamically generated in the actual code and cannot have a fixed or constant value. I tried using the * symbol as a wildcard for the RequestReference but it did not work.
My Question:
How can I make the RequestReference field dynamic in the WireMock setup so that the test can match requests regardless of the exact value of RequestReference?
Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated!

You don't need to set the request body explicitly and using the .UsingPost() is enough, if you want to use some of the values in the request in the response model then you should use the JsonPath.SelectToken structure.
var response = new Response
{
    CustomerId = CustomerReference,
    CustomerEmail = _customerInfo.EmailAddress,
    CustomerName = _customerInfo.FirstName + " " + _customerInfo.LastName,
    RequestDate = DateTime.UtcNow
};

var request = new Request
{
    CustomerEmail = customerEmail,
    CustomerId = customerId,
    CustomerName = customerName,
    RequestReference = "can be anything on the fly",
};

WireMockApiFake
    .Given(Request.Create()
        .WithPath("/api/customer")
        .UsingPost())// no need to set .WithBodyAsJson(request)
    .RespondWith(Response.Create()
        .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        .WithBodyAsJson(new Response
            {
                CustomerId = "{{JsonPath.SelectToken request.body \"$.requestReference\"}}",
                CustomerEmail = "{{JsonPath.SelectToken request.body \"$.customerEmail\"}}",
                CustomerName = _customerInfo.FirstName + " " + _customerInfo.LastName,
                RequestDate = DateTime.UtcNow
            }));


var request = new Request
{
    CustomerEmail = customerEmail,
    CustomerId = customerId,
    CustomerName = customerName,
    RequestReference = "*",
};

WireMockApiFake
        .Given(Request.Create()
            .WithPath("/api/customer")
            .UsingPost()
            .WithBody(new JsonPartialWildcardMatcher(request)))
        .RespondWith(Response.Create()
            .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            .WithBodyAsJson(response));

I fix the issue using this implementation.
